# Simulink Advice Needed: Multiple Instances of GoTo Tags?

Tags: matlab, design-patterns, simulink

I have a library of components for heat transfer analysis (condenser, compressor...).

Now, the way it's set up currently is outputs from individual blocks are sent (using GoTo/From combinations) to an **Output Block** which allows the user to send them to a scope and/or to the workplace.

However, the problem arises when I want multiple instances of one block (example TWO compressors). In that case, the GoTo tags become conflicted because they have the same name. The solution might be to rename them manually, but that is vastly inelegant and not scalable.

I was wondering if anyone else has encountered similar obstacles, and whether they could share their solution here? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Don't use GoTos, route your signals :)

Comment: To add to the previous comment, uses buses if you have a lot of signals. The user can then use a bus selector blocks to select the signals of interest. Either or you need to manually edit your from/goto blocks every time you add an instance of the block in question.

Comment: pmb, am304: Thanks for your advice, and trust me, if I could get rid of the goto/from signals I would. 
Within my 'components'(the compressor for instance), I do liberally use the mux/demux to simplify the routing.
What I want here, though, is that the outputs (for example the Pressure value) from _all_ components be sent to a centralized Outputs component that handles all outputs. This eases things for the user because he can customize how he wants his outpusts (To Workspace, Scope or ignore) all from within one place. For this, I need a way to send copies of signals without naming conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use the signal for logging and plotting I will suggest to [record simulation data](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/ug/record-simulation-data.html). This is much more clean since it does not require any blocks or signal routing for plotting and logging. You can use [simulation data inspector](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/ug/simulation-data-inspector-overview.html?searchHighlight=Simulation%20Data%20Inspector) to "scope" the data and export data to workspace by [export signal data using signal logging](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/ug/exporting-signal-data-using-signal-logging.html).